# How to show an image as javascript popup on loading the page?

Tags: javascript, image, popup

I want to load (Popup) an image from a particular external url to be loaded on my page when I load the page with a small text description. How to do this with javascript?

Comment: can you please elaborate your requirement, What you have tried so far?

Comment: Look at BlockUI. You can do: $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="http://www.whatever.com/yourimage.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });

Comment: I am new to Javascript. So an explained code would be helpful.